# Is there any way to catch a "too many values to unpack" error?

Tags: python

This usage of my subclass of tuple:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, columns=()):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, tuple(columns))

a, b = MyTuple(columns=('hello', 'world', 42))
```

gives the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

A `ValueError` can have many causes, so do I need to use the following to catch it?

```
try:
    a, b = MyTuple(columns=('hello', 'world', 42))
except ValueError as e:
    if not str(e).endswith('unpack'):
        raise  # false alarm
    # handle unpacking error here..
```

that seems rather inelegant.. Is there any way I can override which exception the tuple unpacking raises?

**update:** the actual use case is as follows

```
>>> dice = FactSet()
>>> for i in range(1, 7):
...     dice.add('dice', n=i)
...
>>> print dice.n + dice.n == 10   # give me all combinations that add up to 10
XPROD((dice(n=4), dice(n=6))
      (dice(n=5), dice(n=5))
      (dice(n=6), dice(n=4)))
>>> a, b = dice.n + dice.n == 10  # same as above, but unpack the individual die
>>> a
FactSet([
    dice(n=4),
    dice(n=5),
    dice(n=6),
])
>>> b
FactSet([
    dice(n=6),
    dice(n=5),
    dice(n=4),
])
>>> a, b = dice.n + dice.n == 13  # no result should probably raise a more specific exception?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
>>> ab = dice.n + dice.n == 13  # this is much more awkward and forces you to deal with the error in-situ (which might not be what you wanted)
>>> if ab:
>>>     a, b = ab
```

Comment: It's generally sign of bad design to catch `too many values to unpack`. If you don't know how many items you're going to unpack it's better to avoid unpacking at all.

Comment: What do you plan to do about it? What does "handle unpacking error here.." really mean? The only reasonable way to go about this is to put the result in a single variable and check the length of the iterable and act acordingly.

Comment: That might be true in general for regular tuples, however, this is for a module that implements operations over containers, i.e.:  `a, b = (a.date - b.date) < datetime.timedelta(days=2)` will give back the items from `a` and `b` such that the difference between their date fields is less than 2 days -- or nothing if the constraints cannot be satisfied.

Comment: if there are use cases in which you need to unpack a variable number of arguments, it should be clear from the context, and you should probably be calling a method or passing an argument specific to those cases

Comment: @eqzx the  usage of arguments was purely to keep the example simple, read my other comment for the actual use-case.

Comment: Store the result in some variable and check `len(all_the_stuff_to_assign_to) == len(to_be_assigned)` before actually doing the assignment, then raise come custom exception.

Comment: @tobias_k how is that more elegant?

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `ab = ...; a, b = ab[0], ab[1]`, this will give you an `IndexError` or a `TypeError`, depending on what `ab` is, instead of a `ValueError`. However, for readability I would still go with the explicit `if`-check...

Comment: @tobias_k see my updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
a, b = <expression>
```

Do:

```
value = <expression>
try:
    a, b = value
except ValueError:
    ...
```

This is the general approach for this kind of problem: when your statement may raise the same kind of exception for more than a reason, simply break the statement into multiple parts, isolating the "critical" part from the rest of the code.

---

> Is there any way I can override which exception the tuple unpacking raises?

No. The exception is not raised by the `tuple` object, it is raised by the Python interpreter. When you do: `a, b, ..., z = something`, the interpreter is executing the following code behind the scenes:

```
it = iter(something)

try:
    a = next(it)
    b = next(it)
    ...
    z = next(it)
except StopIteration:
    raise ValueError('need more than X values to unpack')

try:
    next(it)
except StopIteration:
    pass
else:
    raise ValueError('too many values to unpack (expected Y)')
```

As you can see, the tuple (or the iterable, in the general case) is only being iterated. It does not know what's going on.

And as you can see by reading [CPython's source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b4cbecbc0781/Python/ceval.c#l3774), those exceptions are hard-coded and cannot be "overridden".

Comment: Note that the question is asking about overriding the exception tuple unpacking is raising, from within the tuple subclass.  Not about how to write the exception handling machinery.

Comment: Does that mean that I can accomplish what I want to do by writing my own `collections.Iterator` subclass?

Comment: @thebjorn: mh... yes and no. You need to know in advance how many values to unpack (e.g. you can't write both `a, b = mytuple` and `a, b, c = mytuple`), and your tuple subclass won't behave as expected (e.g. `list(mytuple)` will throw weird exceptions).

Comment: @thebjorn: reading your use case, I believe you are adding clutter and uncertainty. An experienced Python developer would be really surprised to see your custom exception raised by a statement like `a, b = dice.n + dice.n == 13`.

Comment: You're might be correct, however the concept of working declaratively on collections of items (rather than imperatively iterating) is very powerful and makes for some rather elegant solutions to certain problems. Getting the details right is key though (I've been working with Python since version 1.4, so I hope I have some feeling for how DSLs can be implemented in Python).

Comment: Thank you for telling how to isolate operations to catch exceptions more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @AndreaCorbellini's answer, here is a custom iterator implementation that has reasonable/tweakable semantics:

```
import collections


class MyTupleIter(collections.Iterator):
    def __init__(self, mt, length):
        self.mt = mt
        self.pos = -1
        self.length = length

    def next(self):
        self.pos += 1
        if self.pos < self.length:
            if self.pos >= len(self.mt):
                return 'empty-value'
            return self.mt[self.pos]
        raise StopIteration


class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, columns=()):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, tuple(columns))

    def __iter__(self):
        return MyTupleIter(self, length=2)


a, b = MyTuple()
print a, b    # empty-value empty-value

a, b = MyTuple(columns=(1,2,3))
print a, b    # 1 2
```

Comment: FWIW, you do not need to inherit explicitly from `Iterator` (and iterator is simply an object implementing `__next__`). Also, you may implement `MyTuple.__iter__` as a generator, using the `yield` keyword. This should result in a simpler implementation.